# I want to pass two objects into one variable in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

This is what im trying to do.... Both are from my local storage...my "updateProfile" is triggered to "true" when i click on the button to update my form. I tried adding "updateProfile.memberData", but it was not being included when i pass it in my "update" var.

```
update = {
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('memberData')),
      'updateProfile' = true,
    }
```

I have to then pass the update to the server:

```
$http.post(ConfigCnst.restUrl, JSON.stringify(update)).then(function(res)
```

But i seem to be getting an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ."

Comment: Is there any way where i can pass both into the same variable?

Comment: Are you sure the string at memberData is valid JSON?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question... Do you just need to add one more property to object like this? update = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('memberData'));
update.updateProfile = true;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your syntax in building JSON is not correct, try this,

```
var memberData =   JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('memberData'))
```

then,

`update = {memberData:memberData,updateProfile:true }`

you can retrieve the update values as below,

```
 update.memberData
 update.updateProfile
```

Comment: Im getting invalid token from my server. Is there a way to make updateProfile into an object aswell?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

update = { localdata : JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('memberData')),
      updateProfile : true
    }

Comment: Im getting a invalid token from my server reply. It seems to be taking in all the "memberdata" but not the updateProfile.